# Ensuring all the data gets received through UDP socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

Possibly related questions that seem close but don't describe my issue as I understand it:

- [Reading all the data from a UDP socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026316/reading-all-the-data-from-a-udp-socket)
- [Python UDP socket semi-randomly failing to receive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536613/python-udp-socket-semi-randomly-failing-to-receive)
- [Python raw socket listening for UDP packets; only half of the packets received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969259/python-raw-socket-listening-for-udp-packets-only-half-of-the-packets-received)

#### problem

Long file sent line by line doesn't go all the way through UDP over loopback.

#### long story

I have a long file consisting of lines and breaks that is identical to what I will get from another program over UDP locally. Let me emphasize that **the program sending the packets will do so over UDP (there is no choice here), and cannot be feasibly modified to process ACK requests etc. while sending.**

It looks like this (this is the tail):

```
StimulusTime 56398

Signal(0,2) -79.5457

Signal(0,4) -81.7426

Signal(0,6) -83.9978

Signal(0,9) -63.3755

Signal(0,11) -15.6045

Signal(0,13) 31.1299

Signal(0,16) 75.7539

Signal(0,18) 98.301

Signal(0,20) 98.301

Signal(0,22) 48.4546

Signal(0,25) 3.73159

Signal(0,27) -49.9798

Signal(0,29) -77.8449

Signal(1,0) -22.0332

Signal(1,2) -60.6384

Signal(1,4) -98.0858

Signal(1,6) -86.4579

Signal(1,9) -68.9173

Signal(1,11) -31.5552

Signal(1,13) 35.2906

Signal(1,16) 77.0686

Signal(1,18) 96.3836

Signal(1,20) 95.7246

Signal(1,23) 25.6074

Signal(1,25) -20.2101

Signal(1,27) -60.2933

Signal(1,29) -83.8169

Signal(2,0) -31.8826

Signal(2,2) -53.5045

Signal(2,4) -89.9895

Signal(2,7) -84.4503

Signal(2,9) -59.7016

Signal(2,11) -12.8569

Signal(2,13) 28.857

Signal(2,15) 58.0577

Signal(2,18) 96.4222

Signal(2,20) 79.783

Signal(2,22) 58.6463

Signal(2,25) -3.24883

Signal(2,27) -45.5

Signal(2,29) -88.8937

Signal(3,0) -18.6625

Signal(3,2) -53.3978

Signal(1,16) 58.784

Signal(1,17) 44.7782

Signal(1,18) 6.247

Signal(1,19) -12.0855

Signal(1,20) -33.7644

Signal(1,21) -49.4406

Signal(1,22) -67.5791

Signal(1,23) -92.0336

Signal(1,24) -93.9841

END
```

I wrote code that takes this file and sends it a line at a time over UDP locally, and then code that receives it and parses it based on the data type.

Sender:

```
import socket
import sys

# Sends udp test data piped in from STDIN to the listener.
# ex: cat sampleoutput.txt | python testsender.py 

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5000

print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP

# Send from stdin
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
  while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line:
      sock.sendto(line, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    else:
      break

  # get from file arg
else:
  myfile = open(str(sys.argv[1]), "r")
  while True:
    line = myfile.readline()
    if line:
      sock.sendto(line, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    else:
      break


sock.close()
```

Listener:

```
import socket
from array import array

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,  # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)  # buffer size arg

    print data
    # write to file for later testing
    # file = open("testdummy.txt", "a")
    # file.write(data)
    if data == "END\n":
        break
```

I was able to use the above listener to produce the test file from the original program, so it should work. Unfortunately, it fails around 500 lines of payload, as tested by `tail -n 500 testdummy.txt | python testsender.py`, although it's somewhat random. Specifically, the listener does not receive all of the sent lines before the sender exits, leaving it hanging, waiting for the `"END\n"` string.

As I understand it, the socket is already in blocking mode--how can I prevent this from occurring?

Comment: UDP is unreliable, it makes no assurances that all the data will go through. If you send too quickly, kernel buffers fill up and it starts discarding them.

Comment: If you don't want to use TCP, which ensures sequential transport, you have to implement your own logic to detect missing packets and resend them. This is why UDP is rarely used for bulk transmissions.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034680/reliability-of-udp-on-localhost .

Answer (score 1):

My first advice to you, Don't use UDP if you want to transfer files with the sequence of lines preserved, Use TCP if you don't want to code alot. The reasons are;

1. UDP is an unreliable Protocol, in the sense a Packet sent is not guaranteed to be received by the recipient.
2. UDP doesn't guarantee the sequence of packets being received, This is because UDP packets may go to recipient via several routes (Hops between computers). So latter sent packets can take a short route and reach the recipient before former sent packets. ("End\n" packet can come before other packets)

TCP on the other hand is reliable and sequence of packets received is guaranteed. Ideal for file transfer.

But don't worry File sharing applications like Bear Share, Bit Torrents make use of UDP but there are some additional coding you have to do.

1. You need to implement an Acknowledgement protocol, as in you need to have a unique id for each packet you send to the recipient and when the packet is received recipient should send an Acknowledgement packet back to the sender with that id saying the packet was received.
2. If in case the packet got lost and didn't reach the recipient (No Acknowledgement from recipient) you must resend the packet again (and again) until you get the Acknowledgement.
3. You can control the order by not sending the next packet until you get the Acknowledgement for the previous one.

Comment: This is an informative answer, but there's no diagnosis of my problem.

Comment: You used UDP.  UDP is unreliable.  Therefore some packets are lost.  It looks like a diagnosis to me.

Comment: *"Doctor, it hurts when I do this!" "Well, don't do that!"* Repeating the accepted dogma available on all the related questions I linked to does not contribute to this question or the site in general. This answer is so general that it would be a good fit for Wikibooks. The most constructive post on this question, as of this writing, is that of @barmar's, which has some useful things to say (kernel buffers etc.) about my specific issue.